# Add a video to the product gallery in Woocommerce without plugin

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, code-snippets, image-gallery

I'm trying to add a video to the product gallery in Woocommerce. The workaround I found to keep the speed good is to add the thumbnail for the video as an image and make it clickable so that it links to the video but no matter what I try, my link is added to all images of the gallery. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 'add_video_to_product_gallery', 99, 2 );
function add_video_to_product_gallery( $html, $attachment_id ) {
    global $product;

    // Check if this is the last image in the gallery
    $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();
    $last_attachment_id = end($attachment_ids);
    if ( $attachment_id == $last_attachment_id ) {

        // Get the video URL and thumbnail URL
        $video_url = 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/12345678';
        $thumbnail_url = 'https://test.com/Thumbnail.png';

        // Output the video and thumbnail HTML
        $html .= '<div class="product-video-thumbnail">';
        $html .= '<a href="' . $video_url . '" data-fancybox="gallery">';
        $html .= '<img src="' . $thumbnail_url . '" alt="Video Thumbnail" />';
        $html .= '</a>';
        $html .= '</div>';
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: i would first check if last_attachmenet_id is actually an INT, and that product_get_gallery_image_id is an array array, and loop through that array before you simply state that if a equals b. and what i dont see is the solution if a doesn't equal b.